# Finding the volume using cylindrical shells about the x-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

So I have spent about a hour on this problem and figured it was time to ask for some advice. The problem is to find the volume using cylindrical shells by rotating the region bounded 
by
$$8y = x^3,\qquad y = 8,\qquad x = 0$$
about the x-axis.

I changed the one on the far left to $x = 2*y^{1/3}$.

I said the region of the integral went from $0$ to $8$ and that the integrand is

$$2 * \pi * y * (2* y^{1/3})\,dy$$

I figured the height would be $x = 2*y^{1/3}$ and that the radius is just $y$. Any help would be greatly appreciate since I can't find any help for this online. I searched around and found some similar problems but it still doesn't make sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: The radius, height seem fine.

Comment: I don't understand why you got a downvote.  You showed a lot of work and all you had left to do was the integral.

Comment: Thanks it appears I made a typo the first time I entered my answer? I don't know how that happened. It was odd that I was downvoted, but thanks for fixing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you.  The volume is
\begin{align*}
\int_0^8 2\pi y x\,dy &= \int_0^8 2\pi y \left(2\sqrt[3]{y}\right)\,dy \\
&= 4\pi \int_0^8y^{4/3} \,dy \\
&= 4\pi \left[\frac{3}{7}y^{7/3}\right]^8_0 = \frac{12\pi}{7} \cdot 2^7 = \frac{1536\pi}{7}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized I entered in the 1546pi/7 into the answer and that is wrong.... simple typo costed my a hour of work. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Just to be sure I checked with [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolfr.am/2QTqr6w~).

Comment: How did you check with Wolfram Alpha, for future reference? Also How do I properly show my work in my posts? Thanks for editing it to look better.